# Upload local image to deviantsart

Tags: c#, post

I am trying to upload an image to http://deviantsart.com
On the website it states:

> Upload using our public REST API: POST http://deviantsart.com
>   yourimage.jpg

I am trying to do this in C# like this:

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "file", @"@C:\Users\bla\Desktop\gr.PNG" },
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://deviantsart.com/upload.php", content);

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

But I am just getting the raw html from the site as a response. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why have you got 2 @'s in the string ?

Comment: How do you think Deviantsart is going to access your local hard disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually trying to upload the file, instead you're just trying to send them the path to the file on disk.

I'd recommend using something like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) which should make uploading the file much easier.

```
var client = new RestClient("http://deviantsart.com");
var request = new RestRequest("upload.php", Method.POST);
request.AddFile("pathtofileondisk.jpg");

var response = client.Execute(request);
```